# How to enable a submit button on a registration form if all the fields are filled out and are valid

Tags: jquery

i'm new in jquery and i'm having trouble with the submit button on the form i'm trying to create. When the button gets disabled and i want to enabled it again if all the validations return true, it stays disabled. Can somebody please help me figure this out. This is part of my jQuery code:

```
      //some code...

    $('form>input').blur(function () {
       if (firstName == false || lastName==false || email==false || password1==false || password2==false)
           $('#submitButton').prop('disabled',true);
       if (firstName == true && lastName == true && email == true && password1 == true && password2 == true) //{ //$('#submitButton').prop('disabled',false);
               $('#submitButton').removeAttr('disabled');
       });

  });
```

this is part of my HTML code:

```
 <div id="mainDiv">
    <form>
        <label class="label">first name:</label><input type="text" class="firstName" name="firstName" />
        <label class="label">last name:</label><input type="text" class="lastName" name="lastName" />
        <label class="label">email address:</label><input type="text" class="email" name="email" />
        <label class="label">create password:</label><input type="password" class="password1" name="password" />
        <label class="label">confirm password:</label><input type="password" class="password2"/>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="register" />
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Post your html please. one thing with $(this) I dont think you are referring to the correct button

Comment: the context here is `form>input` .Give an id to the submit button and then disable the button

Comment: i did that and the submit button is still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `removeAttr()` function to remove `disabled` attribute:

```js
$('#enable').on('click', function() {
  $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit" type="button" disabled>Submit</button>
<button id="enable" type="button">Enable</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The context here is `form>input` .Give an `id` to the submit button and then disable the button using the same command you are using now

Comment: i did that and the submit button still does not become enabled.  $('form>input').blur(function () {
           if (firstName == false || lastName==false || email==false || password1==false || password2==false)
               $('#submitButton').prop('disabled',true);
           if(firstName ==true && lastName==true && email==true && password1==true && password2==true)
               $('#submitButton').prop('disabled',false);

Comment: `firstname,lastname,password` How are you fetching the value of these variables. 
`$('#firstName').val()` should be used.
Try putting an alert in place of enabling submit button.
I think your if condition is not getting satisfied

Comment: yes i found out that the problem was that one of the boolean variables i used 2 times for 2 different things and that's why my if condition was not getting satisfied... thanks, now it's working. i just changed the variable name...

Answer (score 0):

Please check following code:

```
                <html>
                <head>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <form>
                firstName <br />
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" /><br />
                lastName<br />
                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" /><br />
                Email<br />
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
                password1<br />
                <input type="password" id="password1" name="password1" /><br />     
                <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled" />
            </form>
            <div id="test">
            </div>
                     <script type="text/javascript">

                     (function() {
                            $('form > input').keyup(function() {

                                var empty = false;
                                $('form > input').each(function() {
                                    if ($(this).val() == '') {
                                        empty = true;
                                    }
                                });

                                if (empty) {
                                    $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                } else {
                                    $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
                                }
                            });
                        })()
                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```